# Where to set icons/logos for @electron-forge/maker-appx?

Tags: electron, appx, electron-forge

I haven't been able to figure out how to specify logos for my Electron app when building an .appx with @electron-forge/maker-appx. I've put logos StoreLogo.png, Square150x150Logo.png, Square44x44Logo.png, Wide310x150Logo.png inside the build directory and added it as assets, but the logos do not override the defaults

```
{
    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-appx",
    "config": {
        "assets": "build/appx",
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simpler way to build an MSIX for your electron app is using the [free Express edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/advanced-installer-express/9n4vqdj7ltb8) of Advanced Installer. Here is a step by step tutorial:

- [create MSIX for electron application](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/electron-msix.html)

To set the logos, just go to "Visual Assets" view in your Advanced Installer project and pick the sources you want (as shown in the 4rd screenshot from the tutorial).

*p.s. I am part of the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out over the weekend